# Webpack and firebase

Tags: firebase, webpack

I currenlty want to start integrating webpack into my js firebase app.

Currently, I have done `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app` and added my required dependencies after.

However, when I do that, it says that it could not find the modules with an npm not found warning in console.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';

import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Is there any way to fix this?

This included in multiple files, as they all require firebase.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it should be working correctly.

Anyway, here is my solution for importing firebase libraries only once.
I have created single file/class, called FirebaseConnector:

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/functions';

import AppConfig from 'src/js/config/app_config';

const FUNCTIONS_REGION = 'europe-west1';

class FirebaseConnector {
    static initFirebase() {
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
            firebase.initializeApp(AppConfig.firebase);
        }
    }

    static getDb() {
        FirebaseConnector.initFirebase();
        return firebase.firestore();
    }

    static getFunctions() {
        FirebaseConnector.initFirebase();
        return firebase.app().functions(FUNCTIONS_REGION);
    }
}

export default FirebaseConnector;
```

Whenever I am using something from the Firebase API, I just import that connector and use objects that returns my `FirebaseConnector.getDb()` and `FirebaseConnector.getFunctions()`, eg.:

```js
import FirebaseConnector from './firebase_connector';

// ...
const sendEmail = FirebaseConnector.getFunctions().httpsCallable('sendEmail');
// ...
```